# VBA to Open/Select Multiple text Files and Find/Replace and then Save/Close them

Tags: excel, vba

0

I have a script to open multiple text files, replace some characters and save/close the files. The code however is only providing me with the option to open 1 file instead of multiple when the selection box prompts. How can I update this to select/open multiple text files at once to run through the 'find/replace' text feature?

Here is the code I am using:

```
Sub looptexttest()

'remove extra characters from text file

Dim sBuf As String
Dim sTemp As String
Dim iFileNum As Integer
Dim sFileName As Variant

'Edit as needed
 sFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(, , , , True)


 If sFileName = False Then
  MsgBox "No File Selected", vbExlamation
  Worksheets("Summary").Select
  Exit Sub
End If


iFileNum = FreeFile
Open sFileName For Input As iFileNum

Do Until EOF(iFileNum)
Line Input #iFileNum, sBuf
sTemp = sTemp & sBuf & vbCrLf
Loop
Close iFileNum

 sTemp = Replace(sTemp, ", ", "_")


'Save txt file as (if possible)


iFileNum = FreeFile
Open sFileName For Output As iFileNum


 Print #iFileNum, sTemp

Close iFileNum

 End Sub
```

This code works, it just isn't allowing me to select multiple files at once.

Comment: Update,I added "sFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(, , , , True)"

However now the break occurs on the next line:

If sFileName = False Then
    MsgBox "No File Selected", vbExlamation
    Worksheets("Summary").Select
    Exit Sub
End If

Comment: `sFileName` is a `Variant` that will contain a `Boolean` (`False`) if the dialog was cancelled, a `String` if one file was selected, or a variant array if mutiple files were selected. You can't just assume a type and do `If sFileName = False`, you need to know what you're looking at first.

Comment: Thanks!  Here is what I have. I break at EOF.  Any ideas?
Sub looptexttest()
Dim sBuf As String
Dim sTemp As String

Dim x As Integer
Dim sFileName As Variant
sFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename _
 (FileFilter:="Text Files (*.txt), *.txt", _
 MultiSelect:=True, Title:="Text Files to Open")
If TypeName(FilesToOpen) = "Boolean" Then
MsgBox "No Selection"
End If
x = FreeFile
Do Until EOF(x)
Line Input #x, sBuf
sTemp = sTemp & sBuf & vbCrLf
Loop
Close x
 sTemp = Replace(sTemp, ", ", "_")
x = FreeFile
Open sFileName For Output As x
 Print #x, sTemp
Close x
x = x + 1

Answer (score 1):

You need better validation for the `sFileName` value. Use the `VarType` built-in function to get an enum value representing its data type; if it's a `Boolean`, the dialog was cancelled. If it's a `String`, `MultiSelect` was `False` and there's only one file selected; if it's a `Variant()` array, `MultiSelect` was `True` and there's *at least* one file selected.

So what you do is bail out if you're looking at a `Boolean`; if it's  a `String`, then you make a variant array that only contains this one file name; if it's already a variant array, then you run with that.

Once the number of files selected (/the `MultiSelect` argument) is made irrelevant (because we're now looking at a variant array regardless), all that's left to do is iterate the array and process one file per iteration:

```
Dim userSelection As Variant
userSelection = Application.GetOpenFileName(...)

Dim files As Variant

If VarType(userSelection) = vbBoolean Then
    'dialog was cancelled
    Debug.Assert CBool(userSelection) = False 'if code breaks here, there's a problem.
    'msgbox...
    Exit Sub

ElseIf VarType(userSelection) = vbString Then
    'single file was selected, userSelection is just a string
    files = Array(userSelection)

Else
    'multiple files were selected, userSelection is a variant array
    files = userSelection
End If

Dim i As Long
For i = LBound(files) To UBound(files)

    Dim currentFile As String
    currentFile = files(i)

    Dim currentHandle As Long
    currentHandle = FreeFile

    Open currentFile For Input As #currentHandle
    'read from #currentHandle...
    Close #currentHandle
Next
```

Consider separating these many concerns into smaller, more specialized procedures - that way your code is working with an array of file names in every case, and the only procedure that needs to be concerned about how `GetOpenFileName` is parameterized, is the procedure that prompts the user for filenames:

```
Private Function GetFilenamesToProcess() As Variant
    Dim userSelection As Variant
    userSelection = Application.GetOpenFileName(...)

    If VarType(userSelection) = vbBoolean Then
        'dialog was cancelled
        GetFilenamesToProcess = Array() 'uninitialized array will have upper bound of -1
        Exit Function

    ElseIf VarType(userSelection) = vbString Then
        'single file was selected, userSelection is just a string
        GetFilenamesToProcess = Array(userSelection)

    Else
        'multiple files were selected, userSelection is a variant array
        GetFilenamesToProcess = userSelection
    End If

End Function
```

And now you can have a higher abstraction level and thus cleaner, more "focused" code in your main procedure:

```
Public Sub DoSomething()

    Dim files As Variant
    files = GetFilenamesToProcess
    If UBound(files) < 0 Then
        MsgBox "No files were selected!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(files) To UBound(files)
        ProcessFile files(i)
    Next

End Sub
```

Where `ProcessFile` is another procedure, responsible for reading one single file:

```
Private Sub ProcessFile(ByVal filename As String)
    Dim handle As Long
    handle = FreeFile
    Open filename For Input As #handle
    'do stuff...
    Close #handle
End Sub
```

Comment: Appreciate the feedback.  The first procedure however is still not allowing for the selection of multiple files.  I'm not understanding how to combine this code.  :(

Comment: @AllaGoretoy whether multiple selections are allowed is specified by an argument to the `Application.GetOpenFileName` method.

Comment: I get an error when I try to remedy this....    userSelection = Application.GetOpenFilename(*.txt), *.txt").  When I leave the paranthesis open/blank, I get the option of only selecting one file: userSelection = Application.GetOpenFilename().  Is there a way I can manipulate the code I have to just perform a replace all for all text files selected?